# How to pass variable from thymeleaf input field as PathVariable

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-restcontroller, path-variables

I have controller:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/languages")
{
    @PostMapping("/{arg}")
    public void testLanguage(@PathVariable String arg) {
        log.info("testLanguage(): " + arg);
    }
}
```

html page:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/languages/{arg}(arg=${arg})}">
    <label>Enter any message here:
        <!--How I should write my input field(what parameters must be added)
        to receive this variable in cntroller as @PathVariable-->
        <input type="text" th:value="${arg}" th:name="arg">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Test with ARG">
</form>
```

How to pass `arg` variable from input field and receive it in controller?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Thymeleaf way to do this.  You'll have to either use JavaScript to build that url `onsubmit`, or alternatively create another controller method to do the forwarding for you.  Something like this for example:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public void forwardLanguage(@RequestParam String arg) {
    return "redirect:/language/" + arg;
}
```

Comment: the question is just: how to receive variable from input field to controller. And for example to see this variable in log

Comment: If that was the question... why is the title `How to pass variable from thymeleaf input field as PathVariable`? (Because the answer to that is, you can't with Thymeleaf.).  If you just want to see the variable in a log statement, use a request param instead of a path param.

Comment: thank you for response. I didn't know that it's impossible. And this is why I can't find any example of how to get this as `@PathVariable` in google search.