# Accessing Spring controller, with @PathVariable using a form and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, path-variables

New to thymeleaf...
I am trying to load an item from a spring controller using a simple form that receives the ID and returns then displays the item.

I verified the controller works because if I manually put the web address in I get the desired result:

```
 http://localhost:8080/item/1000
```

My problem is I don't understand the thymeleaf form design.
Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/item")
public class MyController
    {
    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;


    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public String loadItemPathVariable(@PathVariable Long id, Model model)
        {
        model.addAttribute("item", itemService.getItem(id));
        return "finditem";
        }
```

Here is finditem.html thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}">Header</div>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/menu :: menu}">Menu</div>

    <form id="loadbypathvariable" th:action="@{/item/}" method="get">
        <p>
            What Item do you want?  
            <input type="text" name="id" />
            <button type="submit" >Load League</button>
        </p>

    </form>
   <div>
        <p>
            Item found: <th:block th:text="${item}">item</th:block>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:insert="~{fragments/footer :: footer}">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem seems to be this:

```
<form id="loadbypathvariable" th:action="@{/item/}" method="get">
```

In combination with :

Submitting the form goes to this url:

```
 http://localhost:8080/item/?id=1000
```

I have tried variations like:

```
<form id="loadbypathvariable" th:action="@{/item/{id}(id=${id})}" method="get">
```

But this freaks out because I think it is expecting ${id} to be a variable in the model rather than come from the form.  I can't figure out how to reference the form .

How can I get it to post the item like a path variable style?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843449/how-to-pass-variable-from-thymeleaf-input-field-as-pathvariable/64846572#64846572 -- the fact of the matter is, you can't do this using regular html/thymeleaf, it's just not built like that.  If you want, you can use javascript to do this, or create some helper controller methods.

Comment: I am really surprised by this.  I thought thymeleaf was supposed to be matched well with spring rest implementations.  How do you do it with javascript?